# Episode where the Hulk uproots a tree stump

Tags: marvel, episode-identification, the-incredible-hulk, the-incredible-hulk-1978

In this episode Banner's job for the episode involves removing a massive tree stump; following his first hulk-out the first thing he does is tear the stump, roots and all, out of the ground.

Comment: Do you recall anything else about that scene, or the episode as a whole?

Comment: Is this even a question? What are you trying to ask?

Comment: @JK. - Nu'Daq tagged this with the [episode-identification] and [the-incredible-hulk-1978] tags, which suggests they were looking to ID a specific episode of that series. The body of the question contains a description of said episode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The episode was called *Sanctuary*.

IMDB lists it as having keyword '**tree stump**'

https://www.imdb.com/search/keyword/?keywords=tree-stump&ref_=kw_ref_yr&sort=moviemeter,asc&mode=detail&page=1&title_type=tvEpisode&release_date=1977%2C1982

Here is the hulkout on Youtube